# Adrotator in Windows Phone 8.1. XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, adrotator

I want to integrate admob with adrotator in windows phone 8.1 .

```
xmlns:adRotator="using:AdRotator"
.....
 <adRotator:AdRotatorControl 
    x:Name="MyAdRotatorControl"
    AdHeight="90"
    AdWidth="728"
    LocalSettingsLocation="defaultAdSettings.xml"
    AutoStartAds="True" />
```

it gives me an error like

```
Cannot find type System.Windows.Controls.UserControl in module System.Windows.dll.
```

please give me solution how to use adrotator with windows phone 8.1. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Right now this is not possible because Ad Rotator uses the Windows Phone 8.0 AdMob SDK. The error you are seeing is the same error you will get when trying to use the [Windows Phone 8.0 AdMob SDK](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/wp/download) inside a Windows Phone 8.1 project. See [this google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/rWmP27Z9x60). Until Google releases their AdMob SDK for Windows Phone 8.1, Ad Rotator + AdMob will not work on Windows Phone 8.1.